# Why loop Variable say "i' shows Garbage value at array[i] while hard coded value of that variable don't?

Tags: arrays, vector

I am trying to sort array of structures and then display its sorted values. When I use some variable in the loop, it displays a garbage value of first structure while rest of all values are as they are But when I use variable value, it displays all values correct.
My code is:

```
void classificationClass::sortMyStruct(location *temp)
{
    const int loopLimit = _tempVec.size()*_tempVec[0].size();
    double *_temp = (double*)malloc(sizeof(double));
    int *_tempX = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)), *_tempY = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    for (int a = 0; a < loopLimit; a++)
    {
        for (int b = 0; b< loopLimit; b++)
        {
            if (temp[b].value > temp[b+1].value)
            {
                *_temp = temp[b].value;
                *_tempX = temp[b].xLoc;
                *_tempY = temp[b].yLoc;

                temp[b].value = temp[b+1].value;
                temp[b].xLoc = temp[b+1].xLoc;
                temp[b].yLoc = temp[b+1].yLoc;

                temp[b+1].value = *_temp;
                temp[b+1].xLoc = *_tempX;
                temp[b+1].yLoc = *_tempY;
            }
        }
    }
    free(_temp);
    free(_tempX);
    free(_tempY);
}
```

Now if I use "17" instead of "loopLimit", I get correct values.
[The output using a variable is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0XnwQ.jpg)
[The output using hard coded value is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zdfwB.jpg)
If anybody can please guide me in a right direction to this problem's solution, I'll be very thankful. I'm stuck on it for like 2 or 3 days now.
Thanks

Comment: `temp[b+1]` <-- what happens when `b` equals `loopLimit - 1`?

Comment: Just applied what you asked and it worked now. Thanks a lottt mate 

Comment: I've put it into an answer :)

Comment: Actually what happened is I put b<loopLimit-1 in the loop and there it went flying  thanks again man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are on the last iteration of the loop this code will be invalid: `temp[b+1]` since `b+1` is out of the bounds of your array.